# SSDT Installation fails for VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, sql-server-data-tools

I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 installed on my machine, i also have SQL Server 2017 installed.

I am trying to install SQL Server Development Tools for BI projects on my machine,i tried installing    'SSDT for VS2015 17.4' , 'SSDT for VS2015 17.3' and also 'SSDT for VS2015 16.5' and everything failed.

```
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Burn v3.6.3542.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\honey\Downloads\SSDTSetup (3).exe, cmdline: ''
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLanguage' to value '1033'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'EnglishLanguage' to value '1033'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLINTEGRATEDSHELL' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLAS' to value '0'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLRS' to value '0'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLIS' to value '0'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLALL' to value '0'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'SKIPENVIRONMENTSETUP' to value '0'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'INSTALLSHORTCUT' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Initializing numeric variable 'TELEMETRYOPTIN' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\honey\AppData\Local\Temp\sql_SSDT_1400_20200530112116.log'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\honey\Downloads\SSDTSetup (3).exe'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Detect 43 packages
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'devenv_DetectKey' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\premium'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 0
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to true.
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting numeric variable 'DEVENV_PROPLUS' to value 1
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to false.
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Condition 'NOT DEVENV_PROPLUS' evaluates to false.
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'devenvLang_DetectKey' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\14.0\intshelladditionalres\1033'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'isoShellInstall_DetectKey' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'isoShellLPInstall_DetectKey' to value '1'
[5290:0FCC][2020-05-30T11:21:16]: Setting string variable 'netfxfullredist_64_DetectKey' to value '4.8.03752'
```

I see it says registry key not found, any clue on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Please try to [run this fixed tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) first.  Try this solution's steps to troubleshoot your issue( including Net Framework Repair Tool)  Also, make sure that your Internet connection is ok.  Besides, uninstall SSDT for VS2015(you would better use `17.4` version) and `remember run it as Administrator`. Please let us know whether it helps or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try these steps:

**First**, please make sure that your Internet connection is ok and your VS2015 has already installed the Sql Server workload.(you can try to check whether you can create a project called `Sql Server Database Project`)

**Then**,

**1)** Please check all the Windows update and install the latest patches.

**2)** use [.Net Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=30135) to repair the Net Framework's problems.

**3)** download [this repair tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) and then run it.

**4)** clean any caches under **%temp%**(`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp`) and then reboot your PC.

**5)** when you restart PC,  turn off any third party software, firewall, Antivirus software and then run **SSDT for VS2015** as Administrator.

**Besides**, you can also try to create an offline installation package for VS2015.

**1)** Open CMD using 'Run As Administrator' option.

**2)** Navigate to installer location using the opened CMD/

**3)** Type the installer filename followed by `/layout` option. Like `SSDT-Setup-ENU.exe /layout 'C:\layout'(the created folder)`

**4)** then run the exe in that folder to install it.

**In addition**, Since your log is not full enough and if your issue still persists, you could use [collect log tool](http://aka.ms/vscollect) to gather the installation logs. find vslogs.zip from %temp% folder. Please upload the file to Onedrive and share the link here.